# Qt Error Debug on qmake crashed what should I do?

Tags: c++, qt

Compiler output:

```
20:06:09 Running steps for project ChatProgramme2...   
20:06:09 Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe"
C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Chat2\ChatProgramme2.pro -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"   
20:06:19: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe" crashed                                       
Error while building/deploying project ChatProgramme2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit)

The kit Desktop Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015_64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.   
when executing step "qmake"
20:06:19: Elapsed time: 00:11.
```

My device's OS is window 7 64bit

I think there is no incorrect in any files because I got all done on mac so I derived All from mac but I can't compiled on window do you know what's wrong with?

Comment: If you add the contents of the pro file one could actually think about it. the error you posted just said it crashed, so currently you are only repeating the topic in your post.

Comment: pro file is                                                                                                 QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ChatProgramme2
TEMPLATE = app                                                                       DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS 

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        chat.cpp \
    server.cpp \
    client.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    chat.h \
    server.h \
    client.h

FORMS    += chat.ui

Comment: @gui You can edit your question to add the content of your .pro in a readable way. Anyway, QtCreator complains about the "kit" you use, you should have a look in "Tools>Options>Build & Run>Kits". You will find the list of all the kits you have and info about possible warnings and errors by hovering with the mouse cursor in the list.

Comment: @BenjaminT I ve found No Debugger and CMake unconfigured thanks:)